# merge audio and video file in android

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, mp4parser

i'm using mp4parser to merge audio and video files, here is below example i have tried but i'm getting null pointer exception at the very first line itself. i have kept audio and video files at desired location in my phone internal memory. if i debug, first line take lots of time & just halts after mins with null pointer error

```
try
{
          H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("/mnt/sdcard/myvideo/video.mp4"));
            AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("/mnt/sdcard/myvideo/audio.acc"));

            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.addTrack(h264Track);
            movie.addTrack(aacTrack);


            Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

            FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.mp4")).getChannel();
            mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
            fc.close();

        } catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,ee.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

whats wrong in my above code?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this 
I have follow few things to merge audio and video.

- 1)Capture Blank Video  Dont use any audio source like
  "mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);"
- 2)save it to the sd card
- 3)it does not support  MIME type=mp3.
- 4)so if we have to merge  video and video. audio must be mp4 or aac
  .**

**5)call the method on button click or On Crete**

- String audiopath = "/sdcard/audio.m4a";
- String videopath = "/sdcard/video.mp4";
- String outputpath = "/sdcard/output.mp4";
- mux(video, audio, output);

**6)Main Code is here pass it only path where you store your video, audio(m4a,aac),Output path.**

```
 public boolean mux(String videoFile, String audioFile, String outputFile) {
    Movie video;
    try {
        video = new MovieCreator().build(videoFile);

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }

    Movie audio;
    try {

        audio = new MovieCreator().build(audioFile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }

    Track audioTrack = audio.getTracks().get(0);
    video.addTrack(audioTrack);

    Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(video);

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
               fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    BufferedWritableFileByteChannel byteBufferByteChannel = new BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(fos);
    try {

        out.writeContainer(byteBufferByteChannel);
        byteBufferByteChannel.close();
        Log.e("Audio Video", "11");
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static class BufferedWritableFileByteChannel implements WritableByteChannel {
    //    private static final int BUFFER_CAPACITY = 1000000;
    private static final int BUFFER_CAPACITY = 10000000;

    private boolean isOpen = true;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;
    private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
    private final byte[] rawBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_CAPACITY];

    private BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
        this.byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBuffer);
        Log.e("Audio Video", "13");
    }

    @Override
    public int write(ByteBuffer inputBuffer) throws IOException {
        int inputBytes = inputBuffer.remaining();

        if (inputBytes > byteBuffer.remaining()) {
            Log.e("Size ok ", "song size is ok");
            dumpToFile();
            byteBuffer.clear();

            if (inputBytes > byteBuffer.remaining()) {
                Log.e("Size ok ", "song size is not okssss ok");
                throw new BufferOverflowException();
            }
        }

        byteBuffer.put(inputBuffer);

        return inputBytes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return isOpen;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        dumpToFile();
        isOpen = false;
    }

    private void dumpToFile() {
        try {
            outputStream.write(rawBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.position());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was really looking forward to this, the code seemed promising. Unfortunately for me, I get an `OutOfMemoryError` on `MovieCreator.build()` .

Comment: I had to import that lib `implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'`

Comment: I also get the OutOeMemoryError  when caling the build method with the valid path :/